# How to access gl_Position variable for a specific vertex?

Tags: c++, opengl

In the vertex shader, the position of the current vertex is stored in `gl_Position` from what I understand. If in the tessellation shader I wanted to change that variable for a specific vertex how would I do that? Does each vertex contain it's own `gl_Position` variable? Is there a way to do something like `vertex1.gl_Position` so then OpenGL would know that I want to modify vertex1's `gl_Position` variable?

Comment: You have just edited your question and changed "tessellation" to "geometry". However that makes it a completely different question. If you have a new question, you have to [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

The [tessellation control shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation_Control_Shader) operates on [patches](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation_Control_Shader#Execution_model), specific groups of vertices that are conceptually tessellated as a bundle. As such, the TCS's inputs are arrayed. The pre-defined VS outputs are aggregated into an array of TCS inputs in the following input interface block:

```
in gl_PerVertex
{
  vec4 gl_Position;
  float gl_PointSize;
  float gl_ClipDistance[];
} gl_in[gl_MaxPatchVertices];
```

So `gl_in[1].gl_Position` is the `gl_Position` value output by the vertex shader for the second vertex in the patch.

Note that, while the array is sized on the maximum supported number of patch vertices, the *actual* limit is `gl_PatchVerticesIn`, the number of vertices in the tessellation patch.

Each TCS invocation [outputs to a single vertex in the output patch](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation_Control_Shader#Execution_model) (which may have a different number of vertices compared to the input patch). TCS outputs are also arrayed, and the built-in outputs have a similar array compared to the inputs:

```
out gl_PerVertex
{
  vec4 gl_Position;
  float gl_PointSize;
  float gl_ClipDistance[];
} gl_out[];
```

Each TCS invocation is meant to write *only* to the output index `gl_InvocationID`. If a [barrier is used](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation_Control_Shader#Synchronization), they can read from output vertices that were written by other invocations (or other `patch` outputs).

[Tessellation evaluation shaders](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation_Evaluation_Shader) operate on individual vertices in the abstract patch generated by the [primitive generator](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation#Tessellation_primitive_generation). However, all TES invocations operating on the same patch get the *entire* output patch from the TCS. This is arrayed in the same way as the TCS input patch, just with an array size defined by the TCS's output patch size.

If the TCS did not write to the predefined TCS outputs, the corresponding TES cannot access those outputs. As such, they're not actually *special*, they have no intrinsic meaning. `gl_in[1].gl_Position` in the TES is only a "position" if the TCS put a position data value there.